# How to get long lived access tokens from Facebook using iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth, access-token

Even after having enabled `deprecate offline_access`, I still get short lived access tokens. I am using the latest Facebook iOS SDK, and I have followed every step of their [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/), i.e. I try to extend it if needed.

What could I be missing?

Comment: I'm just curious.. how do you check if they are yet short lived? Do you track the expiration date of tokens before and after using the calls the tutorial advises?

Comment: `NSLog(@"Facebook access token valid until %@", self.facebook.expirationDate);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides deprecating offline_access, I had to enable the enhanced auth dialog, delete the app from my Facebook profile and re-authorize it with the new dialog. Go figure.